# Laravel 5: View loaded event

Tags: php, events, view, laravel-5

I want to listen the `View` load (or rendered...) event, how can I do that in Laravel 5 using the `*Event::` facade in the `routes.php` file.

Comment: You can use `View::composer()`, what is your need? Share more info.

Comment: What I need is that I want to do somthing common on all the views of my app

Comment: @TheAlpha , This what I need, thank you, add an answer so I can check as resolved, tank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [view::composer](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers) instead, for example, if you want to pass some common data everytime a view is loaded then in this case create a `view::composer` in 'App\Http\ViewComposers' and register it using a service provider like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot()
    {
        // Run "compose" method from "App\Http\ViewComposers\ProfileComposer" class
        // whenever the "profile" view (Basically profile.blade.php) view is loaded
        View::composer('profile', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\ProfileComposer');
    }
}
```

Then create the `ProfileComposer` like this (Taken from `Laravel` Documentation):

```
<?php namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Users\Repository as UserRepository;

class ProfileComposer {

    protected $users;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }

    // Bind data to the view
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('count', $this->users->count());
    }
}
```

So, everytime you load the `profile view` the `$count` variable will be bound in that view and you can use it like other variables in your `view`. That's it. Read more on the [Laravel website](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers).